# UITableViewController edit by cell identifier

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, edit

The ChatViewController of acaniChat has two different types of cells with cell identifiers: `@"MessageCellID"` and `@"TimestampCellID"`. How do I make it so that only the message cells are editable?

Here's what I did. It kinda works, but only the message cells on screen are editable.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [[chatContent cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] reuseIdentifier] == MessageCellId;
}
```

This works for all cells, but is it the correct practice?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [[cellMap objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] isKindOfClass:[Message class]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My "answer" is more of a recommendation that you use a data source check vs a cell check to determine whether the cell is editable. The `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` is a UITableViewDataSource protocol message. The reason it's part of the data source is b/c generally it is data model logic that determines whether or not the data in a particular cell should be editable. In both of your examples, you are using the type of cell as a proxy for the type of data in the cell.

A better check would be similar to the logic you must be using in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to determine which kind of cell to use.

Without knowing the specifics of the data model I can't give you the exact code but it's something like:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self chatDataTypeAtIndexPath:indexPath] == ChatDataTypeMessage;
}
```

Comment: Cool! The second example I give uses the same logic I use in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. So, I guess I'll go with that. It's data model logic because `cellMap` stores references to the objects being displayed in the table view. And, I'm just checking if the object is an instance of the `Message` class.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize your second example was a data source check b/c of the variable naming. I thought `cellMap` was an array of table cells. It's hard to be sure w/o seeing the code and some people do strange stuff. So, yes, I like your second example! If at some point you make some messages editable and some not, you can easily extend your model and then check a property of the object (e.g. `[message isEditable]`).

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the first option, the '==' operator will check for pointer comparison, and will not compare the strings themselves which is done by isEqualToString:

So it should look like:

```
return[ [[chatContent cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:MessageCellId];
```

Comment: Actually, pointer comparison works because `MessageCellId` is `static`.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale can you confirm that the pointer returned by the reuseIdentifier points to the same location? The property is defined with a 'copy' modifier, so I'd assume the constructer copies the value, and the getter might return an autoreleased copy as well

Comment: that's a good point. Currently, Apple implements `copy` by simply calling `retain` for `NSString` objects. This way, memory is saved since `NSString` objects are immutable anyway. Although I seriously doubt it, this implementation could change. So, perhaps `isEqualToString` (although slower) is more robust than `==` here. Anyway, I'm using the second solution I gave because it wokrs.